# Do I need to escape a string which is post parameters to pass in HTTP body?

Tags: java, android, escaping, httpurlconnection, post-parameter

I use HTTPUrlConnection to request a REST API.
I ser "Content-type" header as follows :

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type",
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

I set HTTP body as follows :

```
out = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
out.write(postParameters.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

I don't know if I need to escape post parameters(which is a String) when I set HTTP header and body as shown above.

I just need Yes or No as answer, but would be great if the answer explains why yes or why no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the data you are POSTing is to be interpreted as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, then it **must** have the form:

```
name1=value1&name2=value2&...
```

Therefore, the "value" parts MUST be URL-encoded, otherwise they will not be interpreted correctly.

Using POST with `x-www-form-urlencoded` is just moving the query-string part of the URL out of the request and into the body.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but I don't get whether you mean I need to escape POST parameter or not. Also note that while setting HTTP body I do `postParameters.getBytes("UTF-8")` as shown in question.

Comment: What is the content of the variable `postParameter`? Give me an example? Also, what does your server API expect?

Comment: Example of postParamter is `name=Akash&email=example@example.com`. What do you mean by what does my server expects?

Comment: You can't just URL-encode the whole thing. You need to URL-encode only the "value" parts. In your example, "Akash" and "example@example.com" need to be URL-encoded. However, if you can be sure that no unacceptable characters will be present in those values, then you can skip the URL-encoding.

Comment: Ok. And what about escaping the postParameters? Do I need to escape it if I URL-encode it?

Comment: What do you mean "escape" it? I think you mean the same thing as URL-encoding.

Comment: By escaping I mean replacing few symbols such as $,@,space,%,#,etc... by its escape character equivalent.

Comment: That's exactly what URLencoding does.